# How to blur in CSS only one layer of when you have multiple layers in background-image?

Tags: html, css

I have a circle `image` that contains multiple `image-background` 's  - an image and a gradient.

I would like to blur only the image and keep the edges of the circle sharp. I use this image a few times in my `HTML` code and would like to use different levels of blur in each image -  Like the example below.

I tried multiple solutions online, but neither of the solutions I found fits to circle edges.

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/shir-zabolotny/pen/eYOJVYj)

```
img {
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-image: radial-gradient(#aac0e8, #b9cde5, #dce6f2);
    margin: 0%;
}
```

.

```
<div id="natoTarget" class="infoContainer">
    <div class="infoTitle">
        <img id="imgNatoTarget" src="img\nato.svg" alt="Nato Target">
        <label id="labelNatoTarget">NatoTarget</label>
        <label id="labelNatoTargetSize">(2.3 x 2.3)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="parameterContainer">
        <div id="natoDetection" class="parameterLine">
            <img id="iconNatoDetection" class="svgBlur" src="img\nato.svg" alt="Nato Detection">
            <label id="labelNatoDetection" for="inputDetection">Detection: </label>
            <output id="inputNatoDetection" name="outputParameter">33</output>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parameterContainer">
        <div id="natoRecognition" class="parameterLine">
            <img id="iconNatoRecognition" src="img\nato.svg" alt="Nato Recognition">
            <label id="labelNatoRecognition" for="inputRecognition">Recognition: </label>
            <output id="inputNatoRecognition">33</output>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parameterContainer">
        <div id="natoIdentification" class="parameterLine">
            <img id="iconNatoIdentification" src="img\nato.svg" alt="Nato Identification">
            <label id="labeNatolIdentification" for="inputNatoIdentification">Identification: </label>
            <output id="inputNatoIdentification">33</output>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example: 
[image].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap your image inside a container and blur the image inside it and remove borders from image.

```
<div class="blurContainer">
    <img id="iconNatoRecognition" src="/someimage/path.jpg" alt="Nato Recognition">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parameterContainer .blurContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30.78px;
  height: 30.78px;
  filter: blur(100);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parameterContainer .blurContainer img {
  filter:  blur(2px);
}
```

Hope that solves your issue: fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r6v9g5un/

Answer (score 2):

You could put the img in a separate div with a border, then apply filter:blur(1px) to the img

HTML:

```html
<div class="infoTitle">
      <div class="circleBorder">
        <img id="imgNatoTarget" src="img\nato.svg" alt="Nato Target">
      </div>
        <label id="labelNatoTarget">NatoTarget</label>
        <label id="labelNatoTargetSize">(2.3 x 2.3)</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.circleBorder{
    border: 2px solid #000000
}

img {
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-image: radial-gradient(#aac0e8, #b9cde5, #dce6f2);
    margin: 0%;
    filter: blur(4px);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a wrapper with background over the image and add a filter property to the image:

It would look like this:

HTML

```
<div class="parameterContainer">
    <div id="natoDetection" class="parameterLine">
        <div class="imageBackground">
            <img id="iconNatoDetection" class="svgBlur" src="img\nato.svg" alt="Nato Detection">
        </div>
        <label id="labelNatoDetection" for="inputDetection">Detection: </label>
        <output id="inputNatoDetection" name="outputParameter">33</output>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.imageBackground {
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-image: radial-gradient(#aac0e8, #b9cde5, #dce6f2);
    display: inline-block;
}

.svgBlur {
    filter: blur(1px);
}

img {
    /*Do nothing*/
}
```